# Turn Firestore Item into Count - Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a carpool app and at the moment I've created a Recyclerview that gets all the data from Firestore and displays it. Now when the user clicks on the particular row it opens up a new activity to book a seat. I have a long variable stored that shows the total number of seats avaiable. My question is how can I convert that variable into a count that only certain number of users are allowed to book a seat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int clicks = 0;
clicks++;

if (variable >3){
    button.setEnabled(false);
}
```